# How to insert accordions when adding tables to database

Tags: php, mysql, database, bootstrap-4, accordion

For each table in my database, i need to insert a accordion. So, when I add a table, it should create a accordion with the table name in the accordion's title.

This is my code:

The code that should insert the accordion (.php):

```
<?php
       require 'includes/dbh.inc.php';

       $sql = "SELECT count(*) AS TOTALNUMBEROFTABLES FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = '4grcbd'";
       $result = $conn->query($sql);

       foreach ($result as $row) {
         $accordion .= '                 
             <h3>' . $row['TOTALNUMBEROFTABLES'] . '</h3>
               <div>
                 <p>                
                   my age is
                 </p>
             </div>';
       }
?>
```

Accordion HTML-Bootstrap:

```
 <div id="accordion">
        <div class="card">
          <div class="card-header" id="headingOne">
            <h5 class="mb-0">
              <button class="btn btn-link" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
                Collapsible Group Item #1
              </button>
            </h5>
          </div>

          <div id="collapseOne" class="collapse show" aria-labelledby="headingOne" data-parent="#accordion">
            <div class="card-body">
              Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
```

And my connection to database (dbh.inc.php):

```
    $servername = "localhost"; 
    $dBUsername = "root";
    $dBPassword = "";
    $dBName = "4grcbd";

    $conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $dBUsername, $dBPassword, $dBName);

    if(!$conn) {
        die("Connection failed: ".mysqli_connect_error());
    }
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: `dbh.inc.php` Why are you connecting to the database twice?

Comment: Sorry, that was my mistake.

Comment: What do you want in your multiple accordians. Did you do the simple stuff like writing a query to collect the data you want, and write a loop to process it

Comment: The query is done in the $sql variable. It should run thought all the tables in my database.

Comment: If you mean `SELECT count(*) AS .....` that will return one row, its a count !! You get a single number back from that, so the `foreach` is a bit of a waste :)

Comment: what are you actually trying to output?  You have a select statement which just counts the number of tables

Comment: My idea was to count all the tables that exists in the database, and then call the code to make the accordion

Comment: yeah, but to do what.  What has the accordion got to do with anything?  What I mean is, why are you creating an accordion and what did you think was going to be printed out into it, and where did you think it was coming from

Comment: That's just my idea. I want, for each table in the database, to make a accordion, so I can output data in there.

Comment: so you want someone to write a query for you that will get all the table names in your database and then output them into the screen for you?

Comment: I want to understand how to make it(with code or not). I'm having a hard time trying to code it.

Comment: Sorry I am not trying to be a pain here, but we ___still___ dont really understand what you want to place into each of these accordians other than a card, but a card is normally used to Present Some Data. ... What data do you want the user to see about each of these tables

Comment: I think all have to explain my database? If so, here it is: Each table is a company and inside each company there is employees. I want for each company to make an accordion, and for each accordion return all the employees registered for each company.

Comment: And the idea, then, is so the user can change the data stored in each employee using a modal. That's it.

Comment: right so you want to select every employee and group them by their employer and then use that to create some accordians

Comment: because that is *very* different from what your initial question suggests, and also the only `sql` you have is a query to total the number of tables in the database which is again, quite different

Comment: In my mind, if i have the total number of tables, then i can return that number in accordions. And then i would make another query so i can return the employees data.

Comment: lol, in your mind that's great, but we can't read your mind : - )  I think you need some practice question writing perhaps (it's worth saying the number of tables is not the same as the number of rows, so you wouldn't get the right answer anyway - if you want the number of employers you need to count the `rows` in your employers table)

Comment: I didn't mean to be rude. English is not my first language.Thank you for your answer anyway. I'll try it. But the main question is: how can i return the number of tables and then return the same amount of accordions.The employees is the next step. Or am I wrong?